# Xamarin.Auth : AddMultipartData - How does it work?

Tags: http, authentication, xamarin

My code is as follows

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);

var request = new OAuth2Request("POST", new Uri("https://www.strava.com/api/v3/uploads"), null, StravaAccount);


request.AddMultipartData("file", input, "application/gpx+xml", Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName));
Response response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

The response I get is :

```
{"message":"Bad Request","errors":[{"resource":"Upload","field":"data","code":"empty"}]}
```

https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Uploads-createUpload
(Hence it being called file instead of data - it's just a bad return message).
What am I doing wrong in this call, why is the data not being sent?

Comment: i've tried the obvious and renamed to 'data' btw :-)

Comment: Hi , have you solved this probelm?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT - no, it works fine with RestSharp if I manually pass over the auth token but doesn't work with this

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful for you .(https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Xamarin.Auth.Request.AddMultipartData%28string,%20string%29/)